# How to use struct correctly

Tags: c#, .net, variables

I currently have the following struct

```
struct str_data
        public string Name;
        public string date;
        public double[] values;
        public int volume;
    }
```

I currently have around 10,000 of these and was wondering how I can transport the data held in the `struct` to different functions and classes?

Comment: huh? Care to elaborate what you mean?

Comment: Are you changing the code or trying to get the data out while the code is running?

Comment: What you mean by `transport .. in the`? Please give an example

Comment: a lot of structs == a lot of possible boxing/unboxing == performance problems, use `class` instead of `struct` for such group of properties

Comment: It's very unclear what your *problem* is here. Can you outline what sort of code you expect to work – how will whatever you get as an answer be used?

Comment: @sll, on the other hand, lots of classes == a lot GC. When used correctly, structs can make performance better, not worse.

Comment: How is this question unclear?  He has no problem.  He is simply asking "What is the correct way to pass a structure to a method?" to which the answer is "Pass it by reference by declaring method parameters with the `ref` keyword `void doStuff(ref str_data data)`."  Whether this is the best method is a separate debate.

Answer (score 1):

How about making the methods take `str_data` as a parameter?

```
public void DoSomething (astr_data str_data)
{
    //do your thing here
}
```

Comment: Well that will only copy the reference and not the data. Altho thats probably what he wants. But not what he asks for.

Comment: OP didn't say anything about copying... "Transport" can mean anything in this context.

Comment: "transport the data held in the struct to different functions and classes" that would imply that he want to transport the data and not the reference to the data. He *might* want a memcpy()... or a serialization to whatever ;)

Comment: That's *one* interpretation, yes. Only OP will know better, OP needs to clarify.